# Fatal error with make command

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to write a make file for my project and I am trying to debug issues using

```
make -n
```

command and I finally got it down to

> Fatal error: can't create /bin/st_driver.o: Permission denied

and I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on.

My code is

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -Wall
TARGETS=st_driver

.PHONY: all clean dist

all: ./${TARGETS}

st_driver: bin/st_driver.o bin/st.o bin/er.o bin/hashtable.o
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o st_driver bin/st_driver.o bin/st.o bin/er.o bin/hashtable.o

bin/st_driver.o: src/drivers/st_driver.c src/include/st.h 
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o /bin/st_driver.o -c src/drivers/st_driver.c

bin/st.o: src/st/st.c src/include/st.h
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c src/st/st.c -o bin/st.o

bin/er.o: src/er/er.c src/include/er.h
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c src/er/er.c -o bin/er.o

bin/hashtable.o: src/util/hashtable.c src/include/hashtable.h
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c src/util/hashtable.o -o bin/hashtable.o

bin/list.o: src/util/list.c include/list.h
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c src/util/list.c -o bin/list.o

clean:
    rm -rf bin/*

run_valgrind: ${TARGETS}
    valgrind -v --leak-check=yes bin/CS480_pcc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem's here:

```
bin/st_driver.o: src/drivers/st_driver.c src/include/st.h 
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o /bin/st_driver.o -c src/drivers/st_driver.c
```

You are referring to `/bin/st_driver.o`, and you wanted to refer to `bin/st_driver.o`.

Comment: Oh wow I completely looked over that. That fixed at least that error. Thank you!